# Update specific fields of object in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have a table consisting of consisting of three fields, here is the pseudocode

```
class Table(Base):
    a = Column()
    b = Column()
    c = Column()
```

When I do commit, I want to restrict any change to field "b" irrespective that it is changed in code.

```
t = getObj(c=3) # Gets object of Table with a=1, b=2, c=3
t.a = 5
t.b = 10
session.merge(t)
session.commit()
```

After I commit to database, I make a query:

```
new_t = getObj(c=3)
new_t.a ==> should be 5
new_t.b ==> should be 2
new_t.c ==> should be 3
```

I do not want the new value of `t.b` to persist in DB, irrespective it is changed above or not.

> Please let me know in comments, if anything doesn't make sense in question.

Comment: Would you like `b` to be a read-only attribute in general, or just sometimes?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Just sometimes.

Comment: Have you missed to add the updated object to session before committing?

Comment: @mad_ Yes, added that, please check.